# How to call a function (defined in shell script) in a Perl script

Tags: linux, shell, perl, unix, external

I have two scripts, namely `shell_script.sh` and `perl_script.pl`.

`shell_script.sh` : It has function definitions which, when invoked from Perl script, will execute certain commands on Linux in batch mode.

`perl_script.pl` : It has the code and logic to be implemented, which functions to invoke etc.

The content of `shell_script.sh` file is as under:

```
bash-4.2$ cat shell_script.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function Definitions
func_1 ()
{
  echo "function definition"
}

func_2 ()
{
  echo "function definition"
}
```

The content of `perl_script.pl` file is as under:

```
bash-4.2$ cat perl_script.pl
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Getopt::Long;

my $var1;
my $var1;

GetOptions("var1=s"     => \$var1,
       "var2=s" => \$var2,
       "help|?" => \$help );

if ($help)
{
    HelpMenu();
}

print " Can I call the func_1 (defined in shell script) with arguments here..?? (in this perl script)";
```

How can i invoke the function `func_1()` (which is defined in `shell_script.sh`) in the perl script `perl_script.pl` ?

Comment: What do you want these functions to (actually) do from/in the Perl script?  Return some values to Perl? Or just do their thing?

Comment: Your could possibly call a script that defined and called the function, but depending on what it does, it may be better to rewrite it as a Perl function.

Comment: You can invoke the function like this from the perl script:  `system 'bash', '-c', 'source shell_script.sh; func_1'`

Answer (score 9):

To invoke a shell *function*, the shell needs to know its definition. One way to achieve that is to have the shell first `source` the file which defines the function. And then, without exiting the shell, call the function. From a Perl script, that would be for example:

```
system 'bash', '-c', 'source shell_script.sh; func_1';
```

Answer (score 5):

To use `bash` functions you need to be in `bash`. So that puts you inside backticks or `system` when in a Perl script, where you are inside a `bash` process<sup>†</sup>.  Then, inside that process, you can `source` the script with functions, what will bring them in, and execute them

**funcs.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

function f1 {
    t1=$1
    u1=$2
    echo "f1: t1=$t1 u1=$u1"
}

function f2 {
    t2=$1
    u2=$2
    echo "f2: t2=$t2 u2=$u2"
}
```

and in Perl (one-liner)

```
perl -wE'
    @r = qx(source funcs.sh; f1 a1 b1; f2 a2 b2); 
    print "got: $_" for @r
'
```

where [qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) is the operator for backticks, but perhaps clearer.  I use backticks in case  you need return from those functions. If your `/bin/sh` isn't linked to `bash`<sup>†</sup> then call `bash` explicitly

```
perl -wE'
    @r = qx(/bin/bash -c "source funcs.sh; f1 a1 b1; f2 a2 b2"); 
    print "got: $_" for @r
'
```

Assignment to an array puts `qx` in list context, in which it returns the `STDOUT` of what it ran as a list of lines. This can be used to separate return from different functions, if they return a single line each.  The `a1,b1` and `a2,b2` are arguments passed to `f1` and `f2`.

Prints

```
got: f1: t1=a1 u1=b1
got: f2: t2=a2 u2=b2
```

This makes some (reasonable) assumptions.

If there is no need for the return, but the functions only need to do their thing, you can use

```
system('/bin/bash', '-c', 'source ... ')
```

as in [Håkon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51004707/4653379)

---

<sup>†</sup>  It is `/bin/sh` really, but that is often relegated to `bash`. Check your system (`/bin/sh` is likely a link to another shell). Or ensure that `bash` runs the command

```
my @ret = qx( /bin/bash -c "source base.sh; f1 a1 b1; f2 a2 b2" );
```

See text for the explanation of this example.

Answer (score 3):

It's overkill for this problem, but [`Env::Modify`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Env::Modify) provides a way to make shell functions available in Perl. With `Env::Modify`, you could, say, import the shell functions once and use them over and over again in subsequence `system` calls.

```
use Env::Modify qw(:bash system source qx);

# import the shell functions
system("source shell_script.sh ; export -f func_1 func_2");
# alternate: put  "export -f func_1 func_2"  at the end of shell_script.sh and call
source("shell_script.sh");

# use the shell functions
system("func_1");
$output = `func_2`;
...
```