# How to call shell script function in my Perl?

Tags: shell, perl

I have some functions in  util.sh, I want to call function in util.sh and get the return value.
Does anyone know how to do?

util.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sayhello()
{
    echo $1 "hello"
}
```

I try to call the function in terminal using the command as below, but got the output "can not found the command sayhello":

```
sh /home/adnrew/code/test/util.sh sayhello test
```

and using the code in my perl as below,

```
$returnvalue = system("/home/adnrew/code/test/util.sh sayhello test ");
```

can not work too.

How can I call shell script function  in my Perl?

Comment: For doing it out of a Perl script, see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51004489/4653379)

Answer (score 2):

You could source the shell script into the subprocess by

```
$returnvalue = system(". /home/adnrew/code/test/util.sh; sayhello test");
```

The parent process (a bash shell, or a perl system subprocess) creates a child bash process when it tries executing a bash shell. Anything defined in the script are thus limited only to the child process and will not reflect in the parent process itself.
Sourcing a script (the 'dot' command or just `source`), on the other hand, runs the definition in the same bash process.

Comment: yes it's can get the return value , but also return a code '0' , is it can not to return the code '0' ??

Comment: @georgetovrea The [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) returns a 0 when all is well.  If the return is non-zero then that number packs some info about what went wrong. So zero is good :)  See documentation at the link