# how to return results from shell script to perl?

Tags: shell, perl

I try to get rtt results (like 149.982/150.125/150.280/0.265 ms ) from shell script in perl ,
 now the ping.sh can retrive the rtt results from shell script ,but how to return the results and how to get the return results from shell script in perl ?

call.pl

```
my $answer= system (".  /home/george/ping.sh;getrtt  8.8.8.8");
if($answer == 0)
{
    exit($answer >> 8);
    my $results =  ##how to get the rtt results from ping.sh ???


 }
```

ping.sh

```
getrtt()
{
   if  ping $ip -c 5 -t 5 | grep -oP '[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+\/[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+\/[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+\/[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+ ms'
   then
      echo ##how to retrun the results (ping $ip -c 5 -t 5 | grep -oP '[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+\/[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+\/[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+\/[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+ ms')???
   else
      echo '1'
 fi 
 }
```

Comment: `system` doesn't return output, but success/fail.  You need `qx` ("backticks"), or "pipe open", or -- best -- one of a few good modules -- like `Capture::Tiny`,`IPC::System::Simple`, `IPC::Run3`,  `IPC::Run`.  Can you please search Stackoverflow? This has been discussed _many many_ times

Comment: Also, can you look into the link given in a comment to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59726882/4653379) -- the specific question (about using functions defined in a shell script) is answered at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51004489/4653379)

Answer (score 1):

within the shell function :

1. you can use the `$()` syntax to get the result of the ping in a variable
2. you can echo the result

within the perl program :
 you can open a pipe `|` and read out the shell stdout

file ping.sh:

```sh
getrtt()
{
   ip=$1;
   if result=$(ping $ip -c 5 -t 5 | grep -P 'ms$')
   then
      echo $result
   else
      echo '1'
 fi
 }
```

file graboutput.pl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

local *EXEC; open EXEC,'. ./ping.sh && getrtt 8.8.8.8|' or die $!;
while (<EXEC>) {
 # do something with the result
 print;
}
close EXEC;

exit $?;

1; # $Source: /my/perlscritps/graboutput.pl$
```

Note: the ping on my linux box doesn't have the same format 
i.e. : `5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +5 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4005ms`
so I changed the -oP option of the grep w/i ping.sh