# Is it possible to call bash function from Perl?

Tags: bash, perl

```
admin@admin:~$ function fun1() { echo "abc"; }
admin@admin:~$ fun1
abc
```

I want to call this function from Perl.

```
admin@admin:~$ perl -e 'fun1'
admin@admin:~$
```

There is no output. What do I need to do to run my shell functions and other variables or Perl isn't able to do this?

Comment: I believe that your question is fully answered on the provided page. If that is not the case please explain and we can re-open it.

Comment: That page talks about how to call bash scripts. Not the same thing. I want to call a function outside of shell scripts.

Comment: "_I want to call a function outside of shell scripts._"  -- if a function is in a separate file (?) that still needs to be executed by a shell (bash you say).  Your Perl program (be that a one-liner if you wish) has to do exactly the same as when running a shell script ... Just try it?  Try answers from that page with your "function" (file which is a shell script since you have to run it using a shell)

Comment: There is a difference between outputting files and calling functions defined in the shell. Totally different problem.

Comment: So you want to define your shell function in a running shell (via a prompt), and run that?

Comment: Yes, I want to run a bash shell defined function from Perl. I don't want to create files. I want to work in shell.

Comment: Fine, reopened. Still, see see [How to call a function (defined in shell script) in a Perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51004489/4653379)

Comment: `-e` is used to literally supply a Perl program. You don't have a Perl function named `fun1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function can be exported in bash, then called in a subshell

```
$ function fun1 { echo "abc"; }
$ export -f fun1
$ perl -wE'system "bash", "-c", "fun1"'
```

(where `$` signifies a shell prompt)

Tested in bash 5.1.8(1)

---

If the shell function returns values (by `echo`-ing) and the Perl program needs them then use "backticks" ([qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#qx/STRING/) in operator form) instead of `system`

```
perl -we'$ret = qx(bash -c "f1 args-for-f1"); print $ret'
```

This assigns a (possibly) multiline string, with all lines of output, to the scalar `$ret`. Or

```
perl -we'@ret = qx ...'
```

to have lines of output as elements of `@ret` array.

See [How to call a function (defined in shell script) in a Perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51004489/4653379).

Comment: @CuriousPanda  Fyi: Added a note on how to use return values from a bash function in Perl

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide a way for processes to talk to the bash process in which you want to run the command?

If not, you could start up a new `bash`, and run the command in there.

```perl
my $bash_cmd = <<'.';
function fun1() { echo "abc"; }
fun1
.

system "bash", "-c", $bash_cmd;
```